# Processing/Java interface construct doesnt work

Tags: java, interface, processing

I tried to use an interface in processing.
The interface method `setMapContent(int r, int c, int breite, int hoehe)` doesnt work. Here's how I use it:

The interface:

```
interface MapContent{
    public void setMapContent(int r, int c, int breite, int hoehe);
}
```

The class method where i try to use the Method :

```
void ubdate(MapContent function)
{
    if(usesMapArray == false)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            forR = r;

            for(int c = 0; c < column; c++)
            {
                forC = c;

                if(usesMapSelectedWH == true)
                {
                    //content(c*contentBreite,r*contentHoehe,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                    //function.setMapContent(r,c,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                    function.setMapContent(forR*contentBreite,forC*contentHoehe,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                }
                else
                {
                    println("Please select width and heigth Manually ");
                    //content(c*contentBreite,r*contentHoehe,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                    //function.setMapContent(r,c,(int)random(0,25),(int)random(0,25));
                    function.setMapContent(forR*(int)random(0,25),forC*(int)random(0,25),(int)random(0,25),(int)random(0,25));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(usesMapArray == true)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < mapArray.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < mapArray[0].length; c++)
            {
                if(usesMapSelectedWH == true)
                {
                    //content(c*contentBreite,r*contentHoehe,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                    //function.setMapContent(r,c,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                    function.setMapContent(forR*contentBreite,forC*contentHoehe,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                }
                else
                {

                    println("Please select width and heigth Manually ");
                    // content(c*contentBreite,r*contentHoehe,contentBreite,contentHoehe);
                    //function.setMapContent(r,c,(int)random(0,25),(int)random(0,25));
                    function.setMapContent(forR*(int)random(0,25),forC*(int)random(0,25),(int)random(0,25),(int)random(0,25));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where I try to call the Method:

```
testKarte.ubdate(new MapContent(){
       public void setMapContent(){
           rect(25,25,25,25);
       }});
```

Every time I get an error :

> MapContent(){} must implement the inherited abstract method MapContent.setMapContent(int, int, int, int);

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous class you create doesn't implements the interface MapContent since this interface specify one method with int, int, int, int as parameters and you write `public void setMapContent()` which is not the same signature...
You should change the signature in the interface (remove the parameters) or change the signature in the class definition:

```
testKarte.ubdate(new MapContent(){
         public void setMapContent(int a, int b, int c, int d){

           rect(25,25,25,25);

         }});
```